# Logic for handling remaining days on reboot

Tags: c++, linux, timer, reboot

There is a timer which invokes a function every 24 hours. This function reads a file to get the number of days remaining, decrements it by 1 and writes back the new remaining days to the same file.

Problem: If the system reboots, the timer (which is waiting to be triggered at the 24 hour mark) may not be invoked and the writing to file will not happen. For instance, if the reboot happens every day before the 24 hour period, the remaining days will never be decremented.

I am using C++ program on a Linux system.

What is the logic required to handle this problem.

Comment: Why do you need to count the days remaining (till?) at all? Can't you just store the date X?

Comment: @AndreyTurkin This for tracking the number of days until another event should happen. The event should not happen until say 'X' days has passed. This 'X' days will be initialized in a file.

Comment: I agree with @AndreyTurkin, storing the end date and calculating remaining days based on that would be a more robust system and would avoid this issue

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: If the user modifies the system time, wouldn't that mess up the calculation?

Comment: yes but if you're accounting for a user manipulating the system then all bets are off. They could leave the server off for days or simply modify the file you're saving the days to.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: Correct, I should be able to handle the case where the user keeps the server off for days. When the server boots after the long layoff, it should read this file and find out the number of days remaining and continue with the process. The file will be hidden and encrypted. So he will not be able to access the file.

Comment: This really sounds like an XY problem: what are you actually trying to accomplish? is all you want is to be able to do something after X days have passed? On a potentially malicious system? seems like a very strange use-case.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the best way would be to store the date of last occurence of the other event and compare each in your dayly function. Or alternatively store directly the new date (old date + X days) and also test it directly. That way you would be immune to reboots, provided you test it also at boot time.

As an alternative if you must keep on processing a remaining number of days, you could check the last modification time of the file. A good hint for the number of days to remove would be the value of (last_time - current_time + 12 hours) / 24 hours. It should accept several days without activation and even several activations in few hours. But you should be very cautious on manual actions of that file, including for example a restore after a major incident, and ensure that the content of the file is coherent with its modification time. DRAGONS LIE THERE...

Comment: The second paragraph seems to be the way I should take. But does that work, if the system time is modified?

Comment: @nitin_cherian: If the system time is just adjusted, even by several minutes of even one full hour if you were to manage DST that way it should still be fine. But if there is an error and the system time is off by days or years anything could happen. As a security measure, the function should abort with an error message if the delta is greater that say 5 or 10 days, and log a warning if different from 1 day.

Comment: It's dangerous to give "security" advice without knowing the context. We cannot assume the OP is not writing code for a nuclear waste depot or medical equipment. "Abort with an error message" is certainly not always a fail-safe option.

Comment: @sehe: the rationale behind is to find a way to alert a real human being that something is weird and that a manual action is required. Whether the manual action shall occur in minutes or in days, and whether the actual action should be *abort* or a other fail safe default is indeed context dependant. But IMHO, trying to build an automatic algorithm able to deal with erroneous system dates is hopeless...

Comment: @sehe: but you are right *security* is not the correct word, just the closer that I could find in English. I meant *a way to protect the system against unwanted/uncontrolled automatic actions*. If you can propose me a better word, I'll edit the post